# Database will not connect

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this:

```
<?php
$username = 'md409951db381343'
$password = '*******';
$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'md409951db381343'

if (mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)){
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Sorry, er ging iets mis: '.mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, ik kon helaas geen verbinding maken met de database server';
    exit();
}
?>
```

But it doesn't say anything or do anything. Does someone know how to fix this, or has another idea to connect to MySQL?

Comment: okay so if `mysqli_connect` completes and it doesn't hit a `mysqli_connect_errno` it does nothing. What exactly are you expecting? Also have you looked at logs?

Comment: _"But it doesn't say anything or does anything"_ - that's because of the syntax error the missing semicolon after `$username = 'md409951db381343'` causes. You please go read up on how to configure PHP to tell you about such errors right now.

Comment: You may want to change your database password now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you do this and see if there is an error

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("HostName","UserName","password","DBName") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

according to https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect_errno.asp

Example
Return an error code from the last connection error, if any:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","wrong_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
//Replace above details with your real server deatils

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```